# Data setting in R

Tags: r

It's the data file which contains the information of all households. I want to make a new column father_edu for those females whose ages are between 15-30, keeping in the view that sbq02 (relationship with the head). 
I wanna create a new column on basis of sbq02, sbq04 and age. for example if sbq02=daughter, sbq04=female and age between 15 to 30, then a new column named as father_edu must have the value of scq04 for those who have sbq02=head and sbq04=male

[image]

Comment: The question is phrased very poorly. First of all, don't put links to images. Either provide dput() of your data or a reproducible code. Also, be clear on what your requirement is, otherwise it'll be very difficult for others including myself to help you. On what criteria do you want the column to be created?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you

Comment: I wanna create a new column on basis of sbq02, sbq04 and age. for example if sbq02=daughter, sbq04=female and age between 15 to 30, then a new column named as father_edu must have the value of scq04 for those who have sbq02=head and sbq04=male.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me, you want a new column add if sbq02=daughter,  sbq04 = Female and are aged between 15-30 than you want that to be want? Then if it sbq02=head and sbq04=male then you want the value to be sbq04 value (so male). What about the rows that don't meet either criteria?

Comment: I am giving variable description. So it may clear to you. scq04 is the education reported by each individual of household. And I want to make a new column, i.e father_edu. And this father education must be the education of those only for which sbq02=head and sbq04=male. and this new father_edu must be placed in front of those females who are daughters( sbq02=daughter, sbq04=female) and age between 15 to 30. other rows can be NA's